# How to find the longest matching string from a input string

Tags: mysql, sql

A table, named strings, contains various strings, and unique id's:

[image]

Question is, how to write a query that takes an input string, and return the id of the longest matching (sub) string in the strings table?

The matching string, may, or may not be a substring of the input string. Comparison starts at string index 0.

Inputs and expected output:

```
INPUT -> OUTPUT
ABC    -> 1
ABCD   -> 2
ABCKK  -> 1
ABCDDD -> 2
DAB    -> NULL
CDE    -> NULL
```

Doing this:

```
SET @theString = 'ABCBBB';
SELECT id FROM strings WHERE a_string LIKE @theString;
```

only returns the correct result when the input string exactly matches a string in the table, and don't work when the 'a_string' is a substring.

Comment: I have no idea why this was voted down, but I'm delighted to find my exact question here with a ready-made solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
select s.*
from strings s
where @theString regexp a_string
order by length(a_string) desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Actually, I found an unwanted case and updated the question. For the case of an input string being CABC I would the result to be NULL. Right now, it returns the index 1.

Comment: @TotteKarlsson . . . Something is really not clear.  `'CABC'` should match `'ABC'` because `'ABC'` is a substring (just as the question specifies).  This is the same as `'ABCKK'` matching `'ABC'`.

Comment: I agree something was not properly specified. I changed 5th input record to DAB, correcting the question. CABC is not a match, however, as comparison should start at index 0, as specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In regards of using `LIKE`, you need to set the wildcards for it to work as the filter you want. If you are not required to set a variable, you can use the following query.

```
SELECT id FROM strings
WHERE a_string LIKE '%ABC%'
ORDER BY length(a_string) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

or if you need a variable, it can be done with the CONCAT function

```
SELECT id FROM strings
WHERE a_string LIKE CONCAT('%',@theString,'%')
ORDER BY length(a_string) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This just is an alternative to @Gordon Linoff's answer.